# CSS3 transition for removing text from a menu?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

I have a "collapsing" left nav:

[image: open]

[image: closed]

I am animating the width property of the left nav and the left margin of the main content. It's perfect **except** for the text in the menu items. Since you can't animate a `display:none` I used a jQuery fadeToggle in an Angular directive.  However, no matter how I adjust things, there is too big a "jump".  Any ideas on how to better make the text vanish during the collapse?

**UPDATE:**

I am using this function for the collapse/expand and it seems to work pretty well.

```
var expanded = true;
$menuButton.on({
click: function(e) {
    if (expanded) {
        $('.menu-title').fadeOut('400', function() {
            $body.toggleClass('minified');
        });
        expanded = false;
    } else {
        $body.toggleClass('minified');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.menu-title').fadeIn('400');

        }, 300);
        expanded = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you not animate the width of the text from 100% to 0% ?

Comment: Hmmm. I could try that, thanks.

Comment: Does not work, unfortunately.

Comment: To use the width attribute (and thus animate it), you need to put your text in a block level element.  Give that a text-overflow: clip and overflow: hidden, and it *should* work... (unfortunately I don't have time to mock it up at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rblakeley/3o7qkfmu/) with slide and fade transition, using transform: translateX(-value) and opacity.

You'll have to finish it with the proper browser prefixes (test in Chrome).

You can use a callback function on transitionEnd, if for some reason you need to collapse the 'hidden' element to a width of 0 so it doesn't affect your layout.

```
// callback for transitionEnd
foo.onclick.bind("transitionend 
                  webkitTransitionEnd 
                  oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () { 
    this.style.width(0);
});
```

Comment: Nope.  The text objects still take up space and throw the collapsed nav off. I edited my original post to show something that seems to work, at least on collapse so far.

Comment: Could you describe the space the text objects take up? If the width is 0, I wouldn't expect any...width...on the text object. Is there residual margin or padding possibly?